# iOS - Get peripheral's MAC address from CBPeripheral object

Tags: ios, uuid, core-bluetooth, mac-address

I would like to get the MAC address of the device my iOS device connects to via BLE, but I can see only the UUID.

I've understood from searching the issue over the web that's it's not possible to get the MAC, but only in UUID. I've also understood that the UUID is generated by the iOS and that the device doesn't "know" it...however the posts i've found were old (2-3 years old) so I was wondering if anything has changed? Is there a way to get the MAC rather than the UUID, or at least reproduce the process that iOS does to convert UUID back to MAC address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, nothing has changed. Core Bluetooth is an abstraction layer built on top of BLE.  There is no way of obtaining the MAC address from the identifier and the process by which the identifier is generated is not documented.

Comment: If you pair with the device, the UUID shouldn't change. A way around is to provide a characteristic with the MAC Address (if you have control over the device software). But that's going around the protection and highlevel that is built with iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS not possible to get mac address of CBPeripheral object. If CBPeripheral object advertisement mac address in "kCBAdvDataServiceData" value then convert to mac address, otherwise not possible. In iOS unique id is UUID for CBPeripheral. Every diff. iOS device shows diff. UUID of same CBPeripheral. If differentiate two or more CBPeripheral object then use RSSI range/value.